# Avoid race condition in VBA Access with subquery

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm updating an Access table from VBA Excel with a query containing a subquery:

```
UPDATE table
SET [field] = "username"
WHERE ID = (
SELECT Min(ID)
    FROM table
    WHERE [field] Is Null
)
```

The query is working fine, but when used by multiple users concurrency issues appear which let me to believe that the subquery is subject to a race condition. I've googled the problem and found some confirmations on this, but no real solutions.

Anyone who can give me a pointer on how to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: If you could flesh this out a bit more it would be helpful.  Is the above Update query all that's happening?  Why does it matter who updates the record first?  What, exactly, are you trying to do with this code?  How likely is it that the code will be run at the exact same time by more than one user?  What "concurrency issues" are you experiencing?  All of these questions are important to any proposed solution.

Comment: Race condition? Doesn't make sense here.

Comment: This query is all that's happening. When I execute the query multiple times with multiple users, sometimes an updated [field] value gets overwritten. This shouldn't be happening as the subquery only selects null fields.

Comment: Can you set the `[field]` to save on its initial save? instead of going back to an existing record and updating it.

Comment: Might have to slow the processing down.  Select Min(ID).  Run a DoEvents to let it catch up.  Put Min(ID) in a temp table if Min(ID) doesn't already exist in the temp table.  Run a DoEvents to let it catch up.  Run your code but with an inner join to the temp table to only pull that ID.  Yeah, it's clunky but in theory it should eliminate running twice for the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need a transaction. You need the entire script to be ACID.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208950%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396